# Does the Big Guy have a name?

Tags: names, sanctuary

In the TV series [Sanctuary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanctuary_%28TV_series%29), he's pretty much always called "the big guy" or "biggie" by everyone else, and as far as I know "Bigfoot" is one of the names for his species - not his name.

Has he ever been given an actual name (webisodes, DVD extras, Word of God), is his name *actually* "Big Guy" or "Bigfoot", or has it just been left hanging?

[image]

Comment: I think his "abnormal species" is supposed to be an evolved  Neaderthal, and "Bigfoot" is actually his name. He's credited as Bigfoot in print and the credits, but as @Thaddeus points, no one ever *calls* him that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Unfortunately, he is never named in any of the televised series. I have watched every episode. The scripts list him as "Bigfoot."**

Comment: Yeeaah, that's why I'm asking - I've also seen the whole TV series, but not webisodes/DVD extras/writers' blogs.  The script info is new to me, though.

Comment: Well, it's been quite a while (forgot I posted this question, actually), so I'll accept based on the script calling him "Bigfoot", and hope it doesn't put off anyone else who may have more information.